# Perguntar se o usuário deseja mesmo sair da página?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma página onde ocorre uma task qualquer, só que é necessário finalizar ela, ou todo processo será perdido.
Gostaria de mostrar um alert, como o Facebook e outros sites mostram, perguntando ao usuário se deseja sair mesmo dessa página ou permanecer nela.

Comment: O facebook, como exemplo, apenas emite o alerta quando o usuário escreve algo nos comentários ou no status e não postou. Isso é para evitar  fechar a janela por acidente e perder o que escreveu. É sob esse contexto que vc quer ou é algo geral, independente da situação?

Comment: Exato, nesse contexto mesmo.

Comment: É possível fazer isso pro f5?

Answer (score 5):

Use o `window.onbeforeunload`

**Html:**

```
<textarea id="comentario"></textarea>

<a href="">Sair da página</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    if(document.getElementById("comentario").value != ""){
        return "Deseja realmente sair desta página?";
    }
}
```

Link do exemplo funcionando: **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4x1mhrv/)**

Comment: +1, mas com este código ele dá o alert mesmo quando é clicado no botão pra enviar o formulário... acho que o ap vai ter o mesmo problema... tem como colocar esta exceção?

Comment: Você precisa só adaptar a sua lógica dentro da função, esse é apenas um exemplo, vou editar e adicionar um exemplo.

Comment: é a tal lógica que falta... do que jeito que postou é como uma resposta incompleta. Não está errado, mas está incompleto pois há um contexto específico.

Comment: Fiz a edição, apenas coloque o campo mudando o ID

Comment: Obrigado amigo!

Comment: De nada, caso a resposta tenha ajudado no seu problema, selecione ela como resposta adequada para que outras pessoas possa encontrar caso tenha o mesmo problema

Answer (score 2):

Sob o contexto de que o alerta deve ser exibido caso o usuário tenha um campo preenchido, segue abaixo um exemplo funcional com JQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    console.log("length", $("#foo").val().length);
    if ($("#foo").val().length > 0)
        return "Do you really want to close?";
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="foo" type="text" value="" size="50" />

</body>
</html>
```

A pergunta não especifica o não uso de bibliotecas, por isso utilizei JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque esse script na sua página e teste:

```
   <script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Se você fechar o navegador, seus dados serão perdidos. Desena Realmente sair?";
  }
</script>
```