# Dúvidas sobre javascript em rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Gostaria de saber alguns pontos sobre rails:

Quando estou em uma view de post preenchido e resolvo sair dela, como lançar um alerta avisando que eu posso perder essas alterações?

É possível exibir um post excluído, ou é possível inserir que será marcada como excluída mas que ainda estará presente no banco?

É possível exibir um alerta quando já exista um post com o mesmo título?

É possível que alguns campos apareçam na view de edição mas não apareçam na view de criação de um novo post, já que as duas fazem parte do mesmo form?

[_form.html](https://pastebin.com/6ED0iRxw)

Comment: Amigo, entendo que suas dúvidas estão relacionadas a um mesmo tema, mas tantas perguntas em uma só dificulta enviar de uma solução. Posso adiantar que:
(1) o alerta é possível, você pode ver algo similar aqui:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87290/perguntar-se-o-usu%C3%A1rio-deseja-mesmo-sair-da-p%C3%A1gina

(2 e 3) É possível, eu implementaria com um pouco de AJAX.

(4) Isso você pode resolver no próprio rails, verificando se sua entidade já existe, e fazendo ifs simples.

Sugiro que reformule em perguntas menores.

Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado, Romulo. Irei testar e qualquer coisa volto aqui.